# How/where to find all Update (msu) packages for Windows 7 (Enterprise)

Tags: windows-7, update, patch-management, wim

I've been using Wim2Vhd to create native boot vhd files. (I'm using this to keep several development environments ready, I'm a developer, I know -- I need help ;-)

Now the first boot always ends up in several minutes installing all of the windows updates... I' know I could avoid this if I had a massive list of qfe (.msu) packages that I could supply to the command line of Wim2Vhd.

Where can I find all of the updates so I can download them.

I have found this: http://www.megaleecher.net/Downloading_Microsoft_Windows_7_Offline_Updates
but I'd like a more official source **and** I'd like an easier way to download them all.

I'm a developer, so if I find the information (web service?) to get all the current packages, I'll build a tool to download them to a single location and generate a list of them for use with Wim2Vhd.

Answer (score 1):

I increasingly want a solid, reliable solution for this at work.  I think you need something like [the offline image patching functionality of MDT 2010](http://deployment.xtremeconsulting.com/2009/11/09/windows-update-in-mdt-2010/).